# Unpublished button is disable in my google play console

Tags: android, release, google-play-console

I want to disable my published application but google didn't allow me to unpublished my application,
[image]

Here I'm not able to select the unpublished option because this button is disable

Please help me if you someone faced the same issue in past and able to solve it somehow.

Answer (score 2):

Check the following [prerequisites mentioned here](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9859350)

1. You must have already accepted the latest Developer Distribution Agreement.
2. Your app should not have errors that need to be addressed, such as failing to fill in the content rating questionnaire or provide details about your app's target audience and content.
3. Managed publishing should be disabled for the app you want to unpublish.

Comment: 3rd point worked for me